# State is undefined when using console.log

Tags: reactjs

Im getting confused.. When I try to   **console.log(this.state.podcast[0].collectionId)** Im getting an error saying: **TypeError: Cannot read property 'collectionId' of undefined.**

BUT! If I remove the console.log then everything is working fine..

Im in the learning process of understanding React JS. Can someone point in the right direction?

This is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

export default class Podcast extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props); 
    this.state = {
      podcast: []
    };
  }

  // Fetches podID from props.match
  fetchPodcast () {
    const podcastID = this.props.match.params.podID

    fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${podcastID}`)
      .then(response => response.json())
      .then(data => this.setState({
        podcast: data.results
      }));
  }

  componentDidMount () {
    this.fetchPodcast()
  }

  render() {
    console.log(this.state.podcast[0].collectionId)
    return (
      <div>
          <h2> {this.props.match.params.podID}</h2>
          <ul>
          {this.state.podcast.map(podcast =>
              <li key={podcast.collectionId}>
              <Link to={`/podcast/${podcast.collectionId}`}>{podcast.collectionName}</Link>
              </li>
          )}
          </ul>


</div>
)
  }
}
```

Comment: no data ready on first render

Comment: when your component first loads, `this.state.podcast` is an empty array, so `this.state.podcast[0]` is undefined

Comment: Why does it work when im removing it? And do maping trough this.state.podcast ?? :S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[image: React Lifecycle methods]

Above image will give you a good idea about how React works, check when the `render` phase happens.

So, if we relate this to your case, after constructor call `render()` is called, as `this.state.podcast` is an empty array, `console.log` threw error while you tried to access non existing index value. Also `map` function didn't execute as `this.state.podcast` is an empty array.

Now after `componentDidMount`, `this.state.podcast` gets value, `render` is called again and you get to see collection details.

Answer (score 0):

To see updated state, you can pass a callback to `setState` as second argument:

```
fetch(`https://itunes.apple.com/lookup?id=${podcastID}`)
  .then(response => response.json())
  .then(data => this.setState({
    podcast: data.results
  },()=>{
       console.log(this.state.podcast)
   }));
```

and you can conditionally render your component like this:

```
render() {
const { podcast} = this.state;
return (
  <div>
     {podcast.length &&
      <h2> {this.props.match.params.podID}</h2>
      <ul>
      {this.state.podcast.map(podcast =>
          <li key={podcast.collectionId}>
          <Link to={`/podcast/${podcast.collectionId}`}>{podcast.collectionName}</Link>
          </li>
      )}
      </ul>
      </h2> }
   </div>
```

PS. make sure you're getting data in API response and Javascript is asynchronous. You render method will be called without waiting for the API response. Once you `setState` anywhere your component will be re-rendered. It is showing `podcast` as undefined on first render

Answer (score 0):

When your component first renders your `this.state.podcast` is empty, so your attempt to use it will show as undefined. T**he component re-renders when it receives an update on state and other props.** So when your component initially loads, `this.state.podcast` is undefined, but when it receives the podcast, it re-renders again, showing the values.

Answer (score 0):

Your podcast list is empty when the render triggers. When an array is empty, `Array.map` will effectively run through 0 elements, which is why it doesn't throw an error.
To `console.log` this you could first check the first element exists by using `console.log(this.state.podcast[0] && this.state.podcast[0].collectionId)`, or simply `console.log(this.state.podcast[0])` which will render the whole object if it's defined.